# PHP - Update an XML attribute

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to update XML document. I start with a string that contains XML.

I'm loading that string to [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object:

`$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_string($my_xml_string);`

I find a node that I would like to update like so:

`$node= $xmlDoc->xpath("//nodename[@node_attribute='{$search_attribute_value}']");`

Now I would like to update the `node_attribute` attribute. I try to do `$node['node_attribute']=$new_attribute_value` however  `$node` is it's own object and this doesn't update the `$xmlDoc` object.

How do I find and update attribute value in the `$xmlDoc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$node` you have there is actually an array of nodes. If you know you've only got one to update you can:

```
$node[0]['node_attribute'] = $new_attribute_value;
```

More appropriate may be:

```
$nodes = $xmlDoc->xpath("//nodename[@node_attribute='{$search_attribute_value}']");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node['node_attribute'] = $new_attribute_value;
}
```

And everything will be updated as expected.

Comment: Yeah adding an index to that node did the trick. `$node[0]['node_attribute']=$new_attribute_value;` Not sure what was happening before.

Comment: @dev.e.loper Also note if your node has a text portion, you will use `$node[0]->{'0'}`, as such written [in here](https://eval.in/private/50fd041d061d09).

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you should try like this.

```
$nodename->attributes()->node_attribute = $new_attribute_value;
```